# Filter table from redshift database using R dplyr

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, amazon-redshift, r-dbi

I have a table saved in AWS redshift that has lots of rows and I want to collect only a subset of them using a "user_id" column.  I am trying to use R with the dplyr library to accomplish this (see below).

```
conn_dplyr <- src_postgres('dev',
                       host = '****',
                       port = ****,
                       user = "****", 
                       password = "****")
 df <- tbl(conn_dplyr, "redshift_table")
```

However, when I try to subset over a collection of user ids it fails (see below).  Can someone help me understand how I might be able to collect the data table over a collection of user id elements?  The individual calls work, but when I combine them both it fails.  In this case there are only 2 user ids, but in general it could be hundreds or thousands, so I don't want to do each one individually.  Thanks for your help.

```
df_subset1 <- filter(df, user_id=="2239257806")
df_subset1 <- collect(df_subset1)

df_subset2 <- filter(df, user_id=="22159960")
df_subset2 <- collect(df_subset2)

df_subset_both <- filter(df, user_id==c("2239257806", "22159960"))
df_subset_both <- collect(df_subset_both)

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  operator does not     exist: character varying = record
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts.
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_subset_both <- filter(df, user_id %in% c("2239257806", "22159960"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add condition in the query you uploaded from redshift.

```
    install.packages("RPostgreSQL")
    library(RPostgreSQL)
    drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
    conn <-dbConnect(drv,host='host link',port='5439',dbname='dbname',user='xxx',password='yyy')
   df_subset_both <- dbSendQuery(conn,"select * from my_table where user_id in (2239257806,22159960)")
```